# I am not able to view Chattisgarh state from India, when I am trying to plot map of India with gvisGeochart

Tags: r, gvisgeomap

I have with me data for all Indian states with its population. I have used following code

```
 `G3 <- gvisGeoChart(Population, "States", "Population",
  options=list(region="IN", displayMode="regions", 
  resolution="provinces",
  width=600, height=400))
  plot(G3)`
```

The map comes properly, but data for State Chattisgarh is not getting displayed (data is in the text file I uploaded). 
I have seen a similar graph on web, which also don't display the same.

http://visual.yantrajaal.com/2015/05/googlevis-best-of-r-and-googlecharts.html

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you replace `Chattisgarh` with `Chhattisgarh` (with `Chh...`). Compare the two plots:

```
library(googleVis)
StateMilk <- read.table(
  text = "State 'Cow Milk CD'   'Cow Milk ND'   'Cow Milk Total'    'Buffalo Milk'  'Goat Milk' Total
'Andhra Pradesh'    1268.0  1054.0  2322.0  6603.0  0.4 8925.0
'Arunachal Pradesh' 9.0 23.0    32.0    NA  NA  32.0
Assam   166.0   462.0   628.0   100.0   25.0    752.0
Bihar   986.0   1958.0  2943.0  2623.0  216.0   5783.0
Chattisgarh 56.0    471.0   527.0   296.0   43.0    866.0",
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot(gvisGeoChart(StateMilk, "State", "Total", 
                  options=list(region="IN", displayMode="regions", resolution="provinces", width=600, height=400)))
```

[image: Chattisgarh wont display]

```
StateMilk_with_2_h <- StateMilk
StateMilk_with_2_h$State[StateMilk_with_2_h$State == "Chattisgarh"] <- "Chhattisgarh"
plot(gvisGeoChart(StateMilk_with_2_h, "State", "Total", 
                  options=list(region="IN", displayMode="regions", resolution="provinces", width=600, height=400)))
```

[image: Chhattisgarh displays]